# Repeatedly running a function over a reactive dataframe in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am building an RShiny app that I want to display some outputs based on the a dataframe.

The dataframe is generated within the app based on some UI inputs.

I have a function that I want to run over the dataframe.

I can achieve this once (or multiple times if I repeat the block of code)

But what I'd like to be able it so the function is run x times based on another UI input.

In my example the app should display two graphs.
The first where the sample has 1 added to their age, and the second where this is done as many times as the user input.

```
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Ipsum Lorem"),
  
  # Sidebar with sliders for input numbers 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      sliderInput("n_Age",
                  "Base Number:",
                  min = 100, max = 500,
                  value = 100),
      
      sliderInput("projection",
                  "Number of repeated runs:",
                  min = 1,max = 5,
                  value = 2),
      
      actionButton("refresh", "New Random Sample")
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  
                  tabPanel("Plot", 
                           h4("Graphs of rando numbers"),
                           plotOutput("distPlot1"),

                           br(),hr(),br(),
                           plotOutput("distPlot2")),
                  
                  tabPanel("Table", 
                           h4("Table of invisible numbers"))
      )
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dataInput1 <- reactive({
    
    input$refresh
    
    # creates base data.frame of IDs and ages from Base number
    df01 = data.table(1:input$n_Age, round((rnbinom(input$n_Age, 10, 0.28)+24),0))
    colnames(df01) = c("ID","Age")
    return (df01)
  })
  
  # creates the Ageing function
  fxx1 = function(a) {
    a$Age = a$Age + 1
    a$ID = c(1:length(a$Age))
    a
  }
  
  # runs the Ageing function once 
  dataInput2 <- reactive({
    df01 = fxx1(dataInput1())
    return(df01)
  })
  
  # plots the results
  output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(dataInput2(), aes(Age))+
      geom_bar(width = 0.75)+
      theme_minimal()
      })
  
  ##### THIS IS THE PROBLEM I THINK #####
  # runs the Ageing function x times based on projection slider 
  dataInput3 <- reactive({
    for (i in 1:(input$projection))
    {
      df01 = fxx1(dataInput2())
    }
    return(df01)
  })
  
  # plots the results
  output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(dataInput3(), aes(Age))+
      geom_bar(width = 0.75)+
      theme_minimal()
      })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The above just produces two identical graphs.

I trailed the *for loop* outside of shiny and it works as I want it to, I think the problem is probably that the loop effectively resets each run, always using the same dataframe instead of the product of the previous run, but I can't think of any solutions. Also FYI the real function is a good bit more complicate than my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your plots are not identical. They are shifted by one year. But you are right, your `for` loop is doing nothing, as in each iteration `df01` is computed as `df01 = fxx1(dataInput2())`. Instead I would suggest to init `df01` as `dataInput2()` outside of the loop. Then, inside the loop do `df01 <- fxx1(df01)`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Ipsum Lorem"),

  # Sidebar with sliders for input numbers
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("n_Age",
        "Base Number:",
        min = 100, max = 500,
        value = 100
      ),
      sliderInput("projection",
        "Number of repeated runs:",
        min = 1, max = 5,
        value = 2
      ),
      actionButton("refresh", "New Random Sample")
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel(
          "Plot",
          h4("Graphs of rando numbers"),
          plotOutput("distPlot1"),
          br(), hr(), br(),
          plotOutput("distPlot2")
        ),
        tabPanel(
          "Table",
          h4("Table of invisible numbers")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# creates the Ageing function
fxx1 <- function(a) {
  a$Age <- a$Age + 1
  a$ID <- seq_along(a$Age)
  a
}

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dataInput1 <- reactive({
    input$refresh

    # creates base data.frame of IDs and ages from Base number
    df01 <- data.table(1:input$n_Age, round((rnbinom(input$n_Age, 10, 0.28) + 24), 0))
    colnames(df01) <- c("ID", "Age")
    return(df01)
  })

  # runs the Ageing function once
  dataInput2 <- reactive({
    df01 <- fxx1(dataInput1())
    return(df01)
  })

  # plots the results
  output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(dataInput2(), aes(Age)) +
      geom_bar(width = 0.75) +
      theme_minimal()
  })

  # runs the Ageing function x times based on projection slider
  dataInput3 <- reactive({
    df01 <- dataInput2()
    for (i in seq_len(input$projection)) {
      df01 <- fxx1(df01)
    }
    return(df01)
  })

  # plots the results
  output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(dataInput3(), aes(Age)) +
      geom_bar(width = 0.75) +
      theme_minimal()
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8721
```

[image]